# Multiple RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView Performance issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am facing performance issue while adding multiple RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView. I am displaying two horizontal on top and vertical RecyclerView on bottom.

I have Added below line

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

This is showing all list properly but real question is I am facing performance issue.

All three RecyclerView is showing after ~5 sec of all response come. This is also blocking UI as it busy for RecyclerView to appear.

XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/llTabs"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.turacomobile.gb.utils.CustomSFUIMediumTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMyBrands"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="My Streamz (Brands)"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvMyBrands"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <com.turacomobile.gb.utils.CustomSFUIMediumTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRecommendedBrands"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Recommended Streamz (Brands)"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextStyleSearch"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvRecommendedBrands"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <com.turacomobile.gb.utils.CustomSFUIMediumTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSearchMyStreamz"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Food from My Streamz Brands"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

JAVA

```
    rvSearchStreamz = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    rvMyBrands = findViewById(R.id.rvMyBrands);
    rvRecommendedBrands = findViewById(R.id.rvRecommendedBrands);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rvSearchStreamz.setLayoutManager(llm);
    rvSearchStreamz.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    rvSearchStreamz.setHasFixedSize(false);

    LinearLayoutManager llmMy = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llmMy.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    rvMyBrands.setLayoutManager(llmMy);
    rvMyBrands.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    rvMyBrands.setHasFixedSize(false);

    LinearLayoutManager llmRecommended = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llmRecommended.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    rvRecommendedBrands.setLayoutManager(llmRecommended);
    rvRecommendedBrands.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    rvRecommendedBrands.setHasFixedSize(false);
```

Comment: can you share code for  your `recyclerView`

Comment: @Nilu Added xml and java code

Answer (score 5):

The problem is NestedScrollView. You shouldn't use RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView because RecyclerView don't recycle anything in a NestedScrollView(You can test it with write log in onCreateView and onBindView). Change the container layout type like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc.

Comment: I got your point. Then How can I use three recyclerview in one.

Comment: Maybe you can put your horizontal scrollviews in bottom scrollview's first two item.

Answer (score 1):

At first change Adapter initialize

```
HorizontalAdapterOne hAdapterOne;
HorizontalAdapterTwo hAdapterTwo;
```

And write this to in your onCreate method in Activity

```
hAdapterOne=new HorizontalAdapterOne(context,new ArrayList<DemoItemOne>);
hAdaptertwo=new HorizontalAdapterTwo(context,new ArrayList<DemoItemTwo>);
```

Add a method in your adapter

```
public void refreshList(ArrayList<DemoModel> demoList){
    if(demoList!=null  && demoList.size()>0){
        this.demoActualList.addAll(demoList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

After getting data from API then call this method from your activity

```
hAdapterOne.refreshList(demoListFromAPI)
```

Or You Can use a Custom List View instead of Recycler View for Vertical listing. Check the below list View Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView {
boolean expanded = true;
public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
public boolean isExpanded() {
    return expanded;
}
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded()) {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to go with pagination.
As far as performance is your concern this can act as a best catalyst.

In pagination we download and set only a specific amount of content into recyclerview.

Blocking of UI thread and be drastically reduced also  please go with async task if you have lot of data to render as UI therad is to be maintained as light as possible

below is the link where you can get an idea for the implementation.
https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/pagination-with-recyclerview-1cb7e66a502b